# perl LWP::UserAgent gives a cryptic error message

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

Here's the code:

```
$vizFile ='https://docs.recipeinvesting.com/t.aaaf.html'; 
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->env_proxy;
my $response = $ua->get($vizFile);
if ($response->is_success) {print $response->decoded_content;}
else {print"\nError= $response->status_line]n";}
```

I get the message:

```
Error= HTTP::Response=HASH(0x3a9b810)->status_line]n
```

The url works fine if I put it in a browser.

This was working consistently (with plain http, using LWP::Simple), until the site made some changes.

Could it be the https that's making the difference?

Is there some way to get a less cryptic error message?

Comment: To get the real error message, change it to print"\nError= ", $response->status_line, "]\n"

Comment: Method calls are not interpolated in double quotes.

Comment: Tip: You should ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`. If you're already using them, ignore this :) (They would not have helped in this specific situation.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put code in string literals and expect it to get executed. Sure, you can place variables for interpolation, but the making method calls falls on the other side of what's supported.

Replace

```perl
print"\nError= $response->status_line]n";
```

with

```perl
print "\nError= " . $response->status_line . "\n";
```

or

```perl
use feature qw( say );

say "\nError= " . $response->status_line;
```

This will print the status line as desired.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness, this will also work: `print "Error= @{[ $response->status_line ]}\n"`.

Comment: @Guido Flohr, There's a lot of things that work. But that doesn't mean you should use them.    `".( ... )."` isn't really any longer than `@{[ ... ]}`, except it has none of the complexity or expense, and it doesn't call the method in the wrong context.

Answer (score 2):

Please see following demo code, it is encouraged to include `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in the code what would assist you to avoid many potential problems

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use LWP::UserAgent;

my $url ='https://docs.recipeinvesting.com/t.aaaf.html'; 
my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new;

$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->env_proxy;

my $response = $ua->get($url);

if( $response->is_success ){
    say $response->decoded_content;
} else {
    die $response->status_line;
}
```

Documentation: [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent)